# Selecting between dates in mysql

Tags: mysql, date

Need to track and bill delivers based on date, for example if a deliver came in After `01/18/2010`  but before `02/11/2010` it would be billed to `Job no. 198`.

I pretty much know it would be:

```
SELECT `no` FROM `jobs` WHERE 'start_date' >'2010-01-18' AND <`2010-02-11`;
```

in order to get `'2010-01-18' AND < '2010-02-11'`, I have to look in the data base of course that defeats the purpose

I am given the `Var=$delivery_date`

And I am stuck right here.
How can I get the between dates without looking each time.

Sample of data base

```
no    Start Date
198   2010 01 18  14:35    
199   2010 02 11  12:10   
200   2010 03 07  12:33    
201   2010 03 31  17:35   
202   2010 05 25  05:05     
203   2010 06 20  01:05    
204   2010 07 14  08:50   
205   2010 07 21  11:31    
206   2010 09 07  03:47
```

I hope I explained it well enough. I look at the manual and other questions but it always seems like they only have one date that is a variable and all of mine are

PS changing the format or method of the tables is not an option unless you can point me towards the time travel section

Comment: Are you saying that if `$delivery_date` is let's say `2010-03-15`, you want to get 200?

Comment: yes that would be what i would want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to find a `jobs` record with the largest `start_date` that's also less than `$delivery_date`. Here's the query

```
SELECT no 
FROM jobs 
WHERE `start_date` < $delivery_date
ORDER BY `start_date` DESC LIMIT 1
```

If `$delivery_date` is set to `2010-02-08`, the above query will return `198` like you expected.

If `$delivery_date` is set to `2010-03-15`, the above query will return `200`.

Comment: yes this will work only i think i would have to do it twice once for an after an once for a before the next start date

Comment: I tried to vote up your answer it was what worked but i guess i need more rep points thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following select statement:

```
SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE date(start_date) BETWEEN "2010-02-08" AND "2010-03-15";
```

so you only take the date portion into account, not the time.

so with your date format it would be something like

```
SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE date(STR_TO_DATE(start_date, '%Y %m %d %h:%i')) BETWEEN "2010-02-08" AND "2010-03-15"
```

Comment: +1 for same answer i was about to give, just one change,  dont you think you should also add `DATE_FORMAT` because its looks like OP has different date format.

Comment: @DipeshParmar: Ok yes... thats true.. didn't look at the specific date format that well... although it might be a good idea to save it the right way so you don't have to many calculations to do while searching

Comment: I think that is what i need only the time has to be in there I know how to change the date formats around to get what i need I am going to try a see if this works ill post if it dose or dose not

Answer (score 0):

thanks to ekad this worked perfectly

SELECT no 
FROM jobs 
WHERE `start_date` < $delivery_date
ORDER BY `start_date` DESC LIMIT 1

after the query the job no i need is first one